# Listening to all transactions on the blockchian

Tags: web3.js, rpc, jsonrpc-api, slots, subscription

I am trying to listen to all the transactions which happen on the blockchain in realtime in an efficient manner.

Initially, I tried to use the [blockSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#blocksubscribe) RPC subscription, but it is unstable as of now and many RPCs do not have the `--rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription` flag enabled.

Is there any other method to do what this method does? I also tried using the [slotSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#slotsubscribe) RPC subscription but the slots it returns are not finalized, and I have to make additional queries to keep polling when they get added.

Answer (score 1):

You have the main ways right, through `blockSubscribe` and through polling with `getBlocks`.

If you have a validator running, then you can also setup a Geyser plugin to stream all blocks directly to some other server. You can read more about that at https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins